# Update facebook insights through webhooks

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-webhooks

I'm building an application that needs to update Facebook ads information and I'm running into an issue. Recently I've found that The Graph API Webhooks feature allows apps to receive real-time notifications of changes to selected pieces of data:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/webhooks

My question about this issue is:
Can be done through webhooks to get real-time notifications for facebook marketing api insights?

Comment: No, that is not possible. (And since the metrics are aggregated for specific time frames, I don’t think that would even make sense.)

Comment: Time frame is something that is possible to be solved (for example by specifying it when you subscribe)

Comment: @CBroe  the main reason is only for time frames?

Comment: Webhooks are to notify your app about events for which it can’t be predicted when they will be happening. Insights “happen” at a specific time though, the insights for the data gathered today will be available tomorrow ... so it would make little sense to distribute that kind of data via webhooks to begin with.